# JestJS: How to test for unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How do I test for a valid unix timestamp?

I tried to use `expect(1509736771).toMatch(/^d{10}$/)`, but this fails as `toMatch` handles strings.

So I see only the option `expect(1509736771).toBeGreaterThan(1)`, which feels a bit hacky...

I did't see a matcher like `isNumber` or something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be sure you use `\d` in your regex to match digits, not `d` which only matches the actual letter.

If that doesn't solve the issue, convert the value to a string:

```
expect(1509736771.toString()).toMatch(/^\d{10}$/)
```

or

```
expect('' + 1509736771).toMatch(/^\d{10}$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
var patt = new RegExp("e");
var res = patt.test(str);
```

And then just test if `res` is true.